# Shell Script - Atualizar página de 5 em 5 minutos

Tags: shell, shell-script, powershell

Estou precisando de atualizar uma página na web (ex: www.google.com) a cada 5 segundos, pois não tenho nenhuma noção de como fazer esse script.

alguém pode me ajudar ?

obrigado

Comment: Se você for o dono da página, coloque isso no Header: <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5">

Comment: Boa tarde Cantoni, faltou algumas informações.
É que precisava para atualizar uma pagina da web qualquer, tipo google.com

Answer (score 3):

Se você deseja chamar uma página a cada 5 segundos, você pode usar o `curl` pra isso, por exemplo:

```
watch -n5 "curl http://google.com"
```

Execute isso em seu terminal, e a cada 5 segundos a página será chamada. Para sair aperte `CTRL+C`.